# Can't seem to get the str to change to an int with this custom game? Python 3.10

Tags: python, windows

#A small game

```
goblin = 20

dagger = 10

sword = 15

axe = 25

print('There is a goblin up ahead, what weapon would you like to choose? A dagger, a sword, or an axe?')

weapon = input()


print('You look around, and pick up the ' + weapon)


if weapon > goblin:

    #A small game
    goblin = 20
    dagger = 10
    sword = 15
    axe = 25

    print('There is a goblin up ahead, what weapon would you like to choose? A dagger, a sword, or an axe?')
    weapon = input()

    print('You look around, and pick up the ' + weapon)

    if weapon > goblin:
        print('You swing the ' + weapon + ' at the goblin, cutting its head off in succession!')

    else:
        print('You swing the ' + weapon + ' at the goblin, but fail to do enough damage. You are defeated.')


    print('You swing the ' + weapon + ' at the goblin, cutting its head off in succession!')

else:
    print('You swing the ' + weapon + ' at the goblin, but fail to do enough damage. You are defeated.')
```

--

I'm trying to make it so that if the player picks an axe, it registers as an int instead of a str. For example, if the player types 'axe', I want it so weapon = 25

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold the weapons in a `dict` and pick them with the input

```
weapons = {'dagger': 10, 'sword': 15, 'axe': 20}
weapon = input() # 'axe'

if weapons[weapon] > goblin:
    print(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, this has solved the issue. Apologies about the formatting, not sure why it messed up...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like a dictionary, maybe a builder pattern will be better for a large scale thing. Here is a working code using dictionaries, you still need to make sure the user input is a valid choice.

```
weapons = {"dagger": 10, "sword": 15, "axe": 25}
goblin = 20

print('There is a goblin up ahead, what weapon would you like to choose? A dagger, a sword, or an axe?')
weapon = input()
weapon_strength = weapons[weapon]

print('You look around, and pick up the ' + weapon)

if weapon_strength > goblin:
    print('You swing the ' + weapon + ' at the goblin, cutting its head off in succession!')
else:
    print('You swing the ' + weapon + ' at the goblin, but fail to do enough damage. You are defeated.')
```

Answer (score 0):

put the weapons on a map, so you can use the input as the key to access the values.
`weapons = {'dagger': 10, 'sword': 15, 'axe': 20}`